# Chaging type of really large columns - Python MemoryError

Tags: python, date, replace, large-data, memory-efficient

We are migrating from SAS to Python and I am having some trouble dealing with large dataframes.

I am dealing with a df with 15kk rows and 44 columns, a pretty large boy. I need to replace commas with dots in some columns, delete some others columns and change some to date.

To delete I found out that this works pretty well:

```
del df['column']
```

but when trying to replace using this:

```
df["column"] = (dfl["column"].replace('\.','', regex=True).replace(',','.', regex=True).astype(float))
```

I get:

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 14.2 MiB for an array with shape (14901054,) and data type uint8
```

Same happens when trying to convert to date using this:

```
df['column'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['column'],errors='coerce')
```

I get:

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 114. MiB for an array with shape (14901054,) and data type datetime64[ns]
```

Is there any other way to do those things, only more memory efficient? Or is the only solution to split the df beforehand? Thanks!

ps. not all columns are giving me this problem, but I guess that is not important

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert with this library but when you have to deal with a big amount of data, you could store the information in disk and read it in chunks.

A good (but not the best I guess) solution could be store it in a temporal CSV file and them, read the file in chunks, dealing with less rows in memory.

1. Original Dataframe
2. Remove the unnecesary columns
3. Store the dataframe in a temporal CSV file.
4. Read the CSV by chunks:
5. For each chunk, perform the column modifications and store it in another final CSV file.

More information over here (a few minutes googling):

- [Why and how to use pandas with large data](https://towardsdatascience.com/why-and-how-to-use-pandas-with-large-data-9594dda2ea4c)
- [Dealing with large datasets in pandas](https://medium.datadriveninvestor.com/dealing-with-large-datasets-in-pandas-ad47100a9424)